# I want to convert some Color Hex in Andorid Studio.But, some of them throw an error?How to fix it?

Tags: java, android, colors, hex

I retrive some data from api.stackoverflow using Retrofit. Here some of them:
 #FFF, #666, #5A8F53, #1B8FBB. And then I want to use them textView.setBackgroundColor property. So, I use Color.parseColor() method.But, there is an error unidentified color. How to solve this problem?

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.p203customrow,parent,false);   
    ImageView imageViewP203= (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewP203);
    TextView textViewNameP203= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNameP203);
    TextView textViewSiteUrlP203= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSiteUrlP203);

    P203ApiStyle.P203ItemsObjects p203ItemsObjects= p203ItemsObjectsList.get(position);
    Map<String,String> mapStyle=p203ItemsObjects.getStyling();
    String backgroundColor= mapStyle.get("tag_background_color");
    String foregroundColor= mapStyle.get("tag_foreground_color");

    textViewNameP203.setText("Name="+p203ItemsObjects.getName()+" BackgroundColor="+backgroundColor);  
//one result--> Name=Webmasters BacgroundColor=#FFF
    textViewSiteUrlP203.setText("SiteUrl=" + p203ItemsObjects.getSite_url() + " BackgroundColor=" + foregroundColor);
 //one result-->SiteUrl=The url BackgoundColor=#1B8FBB

//when I uncommet to this block that error occurs...
  /*  textViewNameP203.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
    textViewSiteUrlP203.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(foregroundColor));*/

    Picasso.with(context).load(p203ItemsObjects.getIcon_url()).resize(100, 100).into(imageViewP203);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: and where is your code?

Comment: I added. I am sorry.

Comment: you are using websafe colors , not hex . so change #fff to #ffffff , #666 to #666666

Comment: I didn't know websafe color. Thank you.   I added this code block to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment , In your code , you are using websafe color instead of HEX color.

> A hexadecimal color is specified with: `#RRGGBB`, where the `RR` (red), `GG`
>   (green) and `BB` (blue) hexadecimal integers specify the components of
>   the color. All values must be between `00` and `FF`.

*For example, the `#0000FF` value is rendered as blue, because the blue component is set to its highest value (FF) and the others are set to the lowest value (00).*

**So you must change your websafe colors to hex colors. 
In your code , please change `#FFF` to `#FFFFFF` and `#666` to `#666666` .**

please check here to see [the available colors sorted by name.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colorvalues.asp)

and check here to see [the material color codes.](https://www.materialpalette.com/)

Comment: I have already done it. #FFF to #FFFFFF programitically But ; I don't find a way to convert web safe color to hex color. I can convert hex color to integer values and then use it as background color. Example: #006699 -->red:0, green:102, blue:153 and use it  Color.rgb(red,green,blue)

Comment: Yes. Okay. Then if my answer helped you to resolve your problem ,please mark its as accepted answer .

Answer (score 1):

Change the websafe color to hex color

```
 //if statement for some websafe color to change it hex color exp #FFF -->    #FFFFFF
    if(backgroundColor.length()==4){  
        char harf= backgroundColor.charAt(1);
        String suffix=String.valueOf(harf)+String.valueOf(harf)+String.valueOf(harf);
        backgroundColor=backgroundColor.concat(suffix);
    }
textViewNameP203.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
```